# Unable to export plotly images to png with Kaleido

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, kaleido

I have never used plotly before, and I have been trying to export a sample image code to png. I have installed plotly and kaleido and ran the code on python 3, but nothing happens.

```
#Here is the code:

import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
    
# RGB Data as numpy array
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],], dtype=np.uint8)
  
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)
fig.show()

fig.write_image("fig.png")
```

According to the plotly documentation, that should do the trick, but I can't get a png image.
It shows no errors, no warnings... it's like python is stuck in an infinite loop. I can't even stop the terminal from running.

I'm using python 3.9.6 64-bit 
I have tried plotly latest version (5.3.1) and an older version (4.14.3), but I've got the same problem. 
`python -m pip install plotly`

kaleido is the latest version (0.2.1), but I have tried version (0.2.0) too.
`python -m pip install -U kaleido`

What could I be doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have tried the same process in another computer, and it worked ok. Any ideas why the first computer won't run the code?

Comment: I have the same problem in jupyter lab. The command hangs forever. Same thing happens if I try `fig.show(renderer = 'png')` or `fig.show(renderer = 'svg')`.

If I interrupt the kernel, the trace shows it hangs on line 192 of base.py: `startup_response_string = self._proc.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 23):

I run Windows 10 Enterprise and this worked for me:

Downgrade Kaleido to version 0.1.0post1 (which is the latest in 0.1.*):

```
pip install --upgrade "kaleido==0.1.*"
```

Then image creation started working. Also see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71621135/660259

Funny thing? kaleido v0.2.1 works fine on windows server 2019, but not on my work-computer Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my windows 10 machine :)

Comment: This worked for me as well ! Many thanks.
I had version 0.2 that used to work perfectly in a previous machine. But since migrating to my new machine, it stopped working causing the exact issue described in the question. Downgrading kaleido to 0.1 has solved the issue.

Comment: For conda users: `conda install -c conda-forge python-kaleido=0.1.0`

Comment: This just saves my day! I am on Windows 11 and it works!

Comment: Worked for me on Databricks. Before that I was getting `Image export using the "kaleido" engine requires the kaleido package`, even though it is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. tried everything. nothing worked! then finally installed orca. and... It worked!!! I would suggest installing Orca for static image write when using Plotly, if nothing works.

```py
fig.write_image('fig1.png', engine='orca')
```

Answer (score 0):

It was --single-process that fixed it for me.

Code is:

```
import plotly.io as pio
                                                                         
pio.kaleido.scope.chromium_args += ("--single-process",)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty weird export errors, ranging from no image at all (timeout?), all subplots were empty (no traces), only some subplots had traces, or all traces were present, but they were not properly aligned with the subplots.

Things worth trying:

- Don't use WebGL, i.e., use `Scatter(…)` instead of `Scattergl(…)` and so on.
  *→This is what I ended up with, and for small plots, it worked without further changes.*
- Disable Mathjax as suggested by *the.real.gruycho*:

  ```
  import plotly.io as pio
  pio.kaleido.scope.mathjax = None
  ```
- Adjust the chromium arguments, as suggested by *Honey Thakuria*:

  ```
  import plotly.io as pio
  pio.kaleido.scope.chromium_args += ("--single-process",)
  ```
- Try NOT to import `plotly.express`, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/152).
- Try orca instead of kaleido (especially if you have large/complex plots and/or data frames, and you run into Chromium's maximum message size (kMaximumMessageSize), see [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/19)):

  ```
  import plotly.io as pio

  # adjust installation path of orca
  pio.orca.config.executable = 'C:\\Users\\your_username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\orca\\orca.exe'
  pio.orca.config.timeout = 600  # increase timeout from 30 seconds to 10 minutes
  PLOT_WIDTH = 1600
  PLOT_HEIGHT = 1200

  # your code ...

  # make sure to specify width and height when using orca, I had issues without
  fig.write_image(filename, format='png', engine='orca', width=PLOT_WIDTH, height=PLOT_HEIGHT)
  ```

  Note: you might need to install orca first, then adjust the path – also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59461863/2738240).
- When using orca, avoid non-ISO/IEC 8859 (or even non-ASCII) characters (Unicode) – at least until exporting works (and then try to add them again to test if this caused the problem).
  For example, I had issues exporting images with orca with the Δ (Delta) character.

Answer (score -1):

Provided you have the `kaleido` installed, you should specify the `engine` as `kaleido` in the object `write_image`.

I could recreate the produce the following with the solution:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

    
# RGB Data as numpy array
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],], dtype=np.uint8)
  
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)
fig.show()

fig.write_image('fig.png', engine='kaleido')
```

Resultant Image:
[image]

Resultant path of image saved:
[image: image_saved_to_path]

Comment: @Karol Duarte, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: No. I have tried that before too, but I get the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

Following the discussion here https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/36 I disabled mathjax

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.kaleido.scope.mathjax = None
```

and voila! plots started to appear.

Apparently this should be fixed from plotly v. 5 onwards, but it's not.

Comment: This one worked for me also!

Comment: @Swap cool, then perhaps upvote

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing the same issues as above.  But stranger, it works on my machine but not on the user's machine.

- We both have Windows Enterprise 10, same version same updates, ... (distributed by Software Center)
- We have identical Python environments (same conda env, distributed by Software Center to all the data scientists, users have no access to this directory to make updates)
- We run the exact same test code from an Anaconda prompt in the same conda env
- We cannot simply downgrade the version of kaleido because of this type of distribution
- For both, it works with ORCA (so it is kaleido posing the problem)

The only difference so far I can spot, is our machine itself.  I run on an Intel, he runs on an AMD processor.

Well, there's actually a second.  I run my Windows in English, he in Dutch.

The people above who don't have this working with 1.2, it could be a suggestion to check your processor.  On my Intel it works, on his AMD it doesn't.

And, for those that don't have it working: are you running on Windows in English version ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32824899)

Comment: Sorry for trying to help, Andrew Ryan