# plotly orca not working on aws ec2 instance

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, anaconda, plotly, orca

I followed [this](https://github.com/plotly/orca) to install `conda plotly-orca` on an AWS EC2 instance (built on `anaconda-python3` image) but hit `Cannot open shared object` error when orca is invoked. The fix is to install `libgtk2.0-0` and `libgconf-2-4` packages which unfortunately are not available on AWS EC2 linux distribution (non `ubuntu`). So I downloaded this standalone [orca-1.3.1.AppImage](https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.3.1/orca-1.3.1.AppImage) for linux.

I use `--appimage-extract` to extract orca-1.3.1.AppImage to `/home/ec2-user/squashfs-root` folder and run:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args "-screen 0 640x480x24" /home/ec2-user/squashfs-root/orca "$@" > /opt/conda/envs/pysig/bin/orca
chmod 777 /opt/conda/envs/pysig/bin/orca
```

However `orca --help` returns this:

```
/opt/conda/envs/pysig/bin/orca: line 1: /home/ec2-user/squashfs-root/orca:: No such file or directory
```

But orca does exist in my `/home/ec2-user/squashfs-root` folder:

```
ls -l /home/ec2-user/squashfs-root/orca
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user 112481216 Jun 29 01:39 /home/ec2-user/squashfs-root/orca
```

On the ec2, I have installed `Xvfb` using sudo, except `libgtk2.0-0` and `libgconf-2-4` packages which are not available in AWS linux distribution.

I run all commands as ec2-user instead of root, because the ec2 is based on anaconda-python3 image, which assigns ec2 as the owner of all the conda stuff.

Any idea why `orca --help` cant find `/home/ec2-user/squashfs-root/orca` when it does exist in `/home/ec2-user/squashfs-root` folder which I have already applied chmod -R 777 over it?

All the examples I can find on the web for `orca on linux` have been on `ubuntu` distribution only, but on github, `Tests and Linux builds` are marked as PASSED. There is zero response from the plotly orca and github communities for the same question asked. The whole experience has been so  clunky and painful, time to look into orca alternative?

Comment: Orca is horrible in my opinion, I've also spent a lot of hours debugging it. I don't know for your specific case, but I have a specific set of install steps I used to get it working in a Docker container. You might look through those steps and see if they help. Find my post on it here: https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/150